# Serial number generation using PHP

Tags: php

I want to generate a series of serial numbers like `CHN000001,CHN000002,CHN000003`, etc using PHP. If there are 100 numbers, then the last one should be like `CHN000100`. If it's 1000, then the serial should look like CHN001000. Can anyone tell me how to implement the "for" loop for this process?

Comment: `+` - is how to add numbers in php, `.` - is how to concatenate strings in php, and here is [`for`](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) documentation

Comment: What about fancying things up a little?  You could encode your serial numbers in [base 36](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36) or including a check-digit for [Luhn validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm)?

Comment: Er, insane?  Really?  Did you SEE your question?  What code are we supposed to help you fix?

Comment: Thanks!  I'll continue to practice my insanity in an effort to improve the quality of StackOverflow content.  BTW, you've had multiple downvotes, offset by a couple of upvotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$x = 0;
while ($x <= 999999)
{
    $numZero = 6 - strlen($x);
    echo 'CHN'.str_repeat('0', $numZero).$x;
    $x++;
}
```

Comment: @BasimSherif I'd also look at DarkXphenomenon's solution as well. It's more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 10):

The following should work. The function you use is [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++)
echo sprintf("CHN%06d", $i)." ";
```